# Weird access with external pointers

Tags: r, rcpp

I made a small reproducible example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class Index {
public:
  Index(int i_) : i(i_) {}
  int getI() { return i; }
private:
  int i;
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP getXPtrIndex(int i) {
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndex: i = " << i << std::endl;
  Index ind(i);
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndex: ind.i = " << ind.getI() << std::endl;
  return XPtr<Index>(&ind, true);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void getXPtrIndexValue(SEXP ptr) {
  XPtr<Index> ind_ptr(ptr);
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndexValue: ind_ptr->i = " << ind_ptr->getI() << std::endl;
  Index ind = *ind_ptr;
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndexValue: ind.i = " << ind.getI() << std::endl;
}
```

Basically, I define a small class, along with a function to get an external pointer of an element of this class. The last function is used to print the weird accessor when returning the class element back to C++.

Results in R:

```
> (extptr <- getXPtrIndex(10))
getXPtrIndex: i = 10
getXPtrIndex: ind.i = 10
<pointer: 0x7ffeeec31b00>

> getXPtrIndexValue(extptr)
getXPtrIndexValue: ind_ptr->i = 33696400
getXPtrIndexValue: ind.i = 0
```

Why can't I access `10`?

I'm using **Rcpp** version 0.12.12 (the latest I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with the temporary object---by the time your second function runs the "content" of the first is already gone.

So either just make

```
Index ind(10);
```

a global, and comment out the line in your first function. Then all is peachy (I changed the R invocation slightly):

```
R> extptr <- getXPtrIndex(10)
getXPtrIndex: i = 10
getXPtrIndex: ind.i = 10

R> getXPtrIndexValue(extptr)
getXPtrIndexValue: ind_ptr->i = 10
getXPtrIndexValue: ind.i = 10
R>
```

Or it also works the same way when you make you `Index` object `static` to ensure persistence.  Corrected example below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class Index {
public:
  Index(int i_) : i(i_) {}
  int getI() { return i; }
private:
  int i;
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP getXPtrIndex(int i) {
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndex: i = " << i << std::endl;
  static Index ind(i);
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndex: ind.i = " << ind.getI() << std::endl;
  return XPtr<Index>(&ind, true);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void getXPtrIndexValue(SEXP ptr) {
  XPtr<Index> ind_ptr(ptr);
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndexValue: ind_ptr->i = " << ind_ptr->getI() << std::endl;
  Index ind = *ind_ptr;
  Rcout << "getXPtrIndexValue: ind.i = " << ind.getI() << std::endl;
}

/*** R
extptr <- getXPtrIndex(10)
getXPtrIndexValue(extptr)
*/
```

Comment: OK I'm not sure I understand. I thought that XPtr was protecting the C++ object from being destroyed. Also using `Rcpp::XPtr<Index> ptr(new Index(i), true);` seems to work. Is it okay?

Comment: Yes, because that actually allocates.  What you had before is governed by C++ scope and gone once the function is gone.

Comment: I'll go with my solution, but I validate your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Techincally speaking, now that `new` somewhere you are also responsible to give that memory back ...

Comment: Using `free(ind_ptr)` is enough?

Comment: The matching for `new` is `delete`; it `malloc` (or `calloc`) and `free`.

Comment: Neither `delete(ind_ptr)` or  `delete(&(*ind_ptr))` work.